# Suspected memory leak (in Sygic); how to interpret the Allocation Tracker

Tags: android, memory

I have an app that uses Sygic Navigation "integrated" into the app.

I have reason to believe that Sygic is leaking memory, since if I disable Sygic in the app, it can run forever. If I however have Sygic enabled, I see OutOfMemoryException after some hours (like 8-10 or something like that).

I cannot say for sure that it is Sygics fault, since the error log/stacktrace does not point specifically to Sygic. Its rather anonymous, and here is a part of it that actually suggest that it has something to do with the GPS:

```
10-23 13:29:23.204: INFO/dalvikvm(7262): "Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=7 RUNNABLE
10-23 13:29:23.204: INFO/dalvikvm(7262):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4051aa20 self=0x8c528
10-23 13:29:23.204: INFO/dalvikvm(7262):   | sysTid=7268 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=574208
10-23 13:29:23.204: INFO/dalvikvm(7262):   | schedstat=( 8254760016 2789215070 4127 )
10-23 13:29:23.204: INFO/dalvikvm(7262):   at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Throwable.java:~135)
10-23 13:29:23.204: INFO/dalvikvm(7262):   at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:74)
10-23 13:29:23.204: INFO/dalvikvm(7262):   at java.lang.Error.<init>(Error.java:38)
10-23 13:29:23.204: INFO/dalvikvm(7262):   at java.lang.VirtualMachineError.<init>(VirtualMachineError.java:36)
10-23 13:29:23.204: INFO/dalvikvm(7262):   at java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.<init>(OutOfMemoryError.java:34)
10-23 13:29:23.204: INFO/dalvikvm(7262):   at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Throwable.java:-1)
10-23 13:29:23.204: INFO/dalvikvm(7262):   at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:74)
10-23 13:29:23.204: INFO/dalvikvm(7262):   at java.lang.Error.<init>(Error.java:38)
10-23 13:29:23.204: INFO/dalvikvm(7262):   at java.lang.VirtualMachineError.<init>(VirtualMachineError.java:36)
10-23 13:29:23.204: INFO/dalvikvm(7262):   at java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.<init>(OutOfMemoryError.java:34)
10-23 13:29:23.204: INFO/dalvikvm(7262):   at android.os.Message.obtain(Message.java:-1)
10-23 13:29:23.204: INFO/dalvikvm(7262):   at android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport.onGpsStarted(LocationManager.java:1230)
10-23 13:29:23.204: INFO/dalvikvm(7262):   at android.location.IGpsStatusListener$Stub.onTransact(IGpsStatusListener.java:51)
10-23 13:29:23.204: INFO/dalvikvm(7262):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
10-23 13:29:23.204: INFO/dalvikvm(7262):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
10-23 13:29:23.449: DEBUG/(2696): [HYPOS] NOMOVE Time 13114, PowerMode 2, GPSWeakSignal 19, GPSFixTime 0, Car 1, DOE 3
10-23 13:29:23.519: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(7262): Clamp target GC heap from 65.442MB to 64.000MB
```

Now, I turn on Sygic and then use the Allocation Tracker. Right now, this is how the heap looks:

[image]

and this is a screenshot from the Allocation Tracker. What I see is loads of allocations. I cannot tell if it looks OK or not. What I noticed was that there are **a lot of allocations** of *android.location.GpsSatellite* and as can bee seen by the stacktrace below, that has something to do with Sygic:

[image]

**My question is:** 
Does this look alright to you? Is there anything from this information that you can say "aha, I see THIS" where this is something fauly, weird etc? Im not sure how to go about it, so Im trying this out =)

*(PS: my app just died, and the only thing I can see in LogCat is a lot of memory addresses, but no reference as to why it died:)*

Comment: I am watching this Google IO video about memory and heap:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk
In there it says that the heap limit is 64MB, and I checked it (using code) in my app and it gives me 64MB as a limit. That means that I have reached my limit, as the GC reports 64MB in heap?

Comment: You also have to be careful so that you watch the correct GC_xxx log messages. The pid must (of course) be the pid of your app/process. So first find out your process id, then watch for GC_xxx logs with the correct pid =)

Comment: WEll, seems like the leak is just when debugging, not when running normally. I think =)

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15170